# How To Save SVG With Transparent Background from InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, svg, transparency, background, file-format

I have an SVG open in InDesign. There are some dark gray letters on a white background. I am trying to make the background transparent and save the result as SVG. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

InDesign does not export to SVG directly. Export your shapes to PDF, open that in Illustrator and save your SVG from there.

Comment: How does one do it in Illustrator, then?

Comment: Open the PDF you exported from ID into AI. You should be able to see your original letters/etc. Choose Save As.. from AI main menu and switch the type to SVG - https://youtu.be/cXBg97PG0yM?t=77

Comment: This will also work in Inkscape too if you don't have Illustrator